# How do I do function calling in Azure Openai using the javascript sdk

Tags: azure, openai-api, azure-openai

I want to be able to call functions based on the user input, I could do this with the openai library but can't find a way to do so in the azure openai library

Below is the code from azure openai in python that is able to do what I want to accomplish

As such I want to replicate this code using the javascript sdk [link](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/%40azure/openai_1.0.0-beta.3/sdk/openai/openai/samples/v1-beta/javascript)

```
import openai 
openai.api_type = "azure" 
openai.api_base = "https://XXXXXXXX.openai.azure.com/" 
openai.api_version = "2023-07-01-preview" 
openai.api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY") 
response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(             
    engine="gpt-35-turbo-XXX",             
    model="gpt-35-turbo-0613-XXXX"             
    messages=messages,             
    functions=functions,             
    function_call="auto",         
)
```

I tried this

```
const response = await openai.getChatCompletions(
deploymentid,       
messages,    
{  function_call: functions }
```

and

```
const response = await openai.getChatCompletions(
deploymentid,       
messages,    
functions )
```

I couldn't find anything on the documentation for this as well

Comment: We need Microsoft to post examples of use of this javascript sdk that include parameters  in general (functions are referred to in this post, but what about sending other parameters like max_tokens and temperature?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The updated Azure OpenAI Javascript documentation now incorporates support for functions and function calls.

You can find the relevant documentation at the following link, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/@azure/openai/getchatcompletionsoptions?view=azure-node-preview

It is recommended that you ensure your Azure OpenAI library is updated to the most recent version.(https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/openai?activeTab=readme)